# How to get the old and new value from a js callback?

Tags: bokeh

When I attach a Python callback to a widget I usually get the old and new values but for a js callback I only get the object and its current value, not the old value. Is this true?

For example, for a slider:

```
def print_values(attr, old, new):
    print(attr, old, new)

slider = Slider(start=0, end=100, value=0, step=1)
slider.on_change('value', print_values)

code = "console.log(cb_obj);"
log_values = CustomJS(args={}, code=code)

slider.js_on_change('value', log_values)
```

How can I get the old value from `cb_obj`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this true?

Yes, as of Bokeh 1.2 `CustomJS` callbacks are not provided with the old property values. It could potentially be considered for new development, so it would be reasonable to make a [feature request issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues).